# How to resolve javax.xml.bind.UnmarshallException?

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I am new RESTful web Services and after going through some documentation I am in a state to invoke a web service. It looks like I am receiving a 200 status back from the service producer when I look at the response object but I am also getting `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshallException`. I get this exception when the code reaches to read the entity. I am a little lost as I am not sure what to do or what to look at in order to resolve this error.

XML Representation of Object

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "Somethig", namespace = "http://respone.something.com" )
@ReleaseInfo( version = "v4", description = "Response for Validate Email 
Service" )
public class ThirdPartyValidateEMailAddressResponse extends BaseResponse {

private String emailAddressProvided;
private String emailAddressReturned;
private String mailboxName;
private String domainName;
private String topLevelDomain;
private String topLevelDomainDesc;
private boolean syntaxCorrected;
private boolean caseStandardized;
private boolean domainNameUpdated;
```

Client Code:

```
public ValidateEMailAddressServiceResponse validateEMailAddress( ValidateEMailAddressServiceRequest request ) throws Exception {

    WebTarget service = config.createWebResource(request.getServiceURL());

    ValidateEMailAddressServiceResponse resp = new ValidateEMailAddressServiceResponse();

    service = service.path(SOMETHING).path(SOMETHING).path(SOMETHING).register(ThirdPartyValidateEmailResponseXMLReader.class);

    ValidateEMailAddressServiceRequestParameter parameter = null;
    parameter = request.getParameter(ValidateEMailAddressServiceRequestParameter.PARAMETERS.emailAddress.name());
    if (parameter != null) {
        service = service.queryParam(ValidateEMailAddressServiceRequestParameter.PARAMETERS.emailA

    Invocation.Builder b = applyHeaders(service, request.getHeaders(), request.getHttpHeaders());

    if(request.getAccepts() != null){
        b = b.accept(request.getAccepts().value());
    }

    Response response = b.get(Response.class);

    try {
        resp = (ValidateEMailAddressServiceResponse) handleBaseResponse(resp, response);


        // Managing business or error response
        ThirdPartyValidateEMailAddressResponse thirdPartyResponse = null;
        if (shouldProcessEntity(SOMETHING+ SOMETHING + SOMETHING, resp)) {
            if (ContentType.XML.equals(request.getAccepts()) || ContentType.JSON.equals(request.getAccepts())) {
                thirdPartyResponse = response.readEntity(ThirdPartyValidateEMailAddressResponse.class);
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Content Type found while processing response");
            }

        }
        else {
            thirdPartyResponse = new ThirdPartyValidateEMailAddressResponse();
            thirdPartyResponse.setMessages(createMessagesFromHTTPStatus(resp));
            response.close();
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new EISClientException("Exception in processing ValidateEMailAddress", e);
    }

    return resp;
}
```

Looks like it fails right here

```
thirdPartyResponse = 
response.readEntity(ThirdPartyValidateEMailAddressResponse.class);
```

stack trace:

```
mig.eis.client.EISClientException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.]
```

Please let me know if anything  else is needed from my side to debug this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Premature EOF indicates the file doesn't have the complete XML. It looks like the XML tags are missing some values. Include the XML so we can see it.

Comment: Thank you for the response Dakoda, but could you please elaborate which XML. Client application has an object with XML annotations on it like XmlRootElement. Are you talking about this because I don't have any XML file.

Comment: Unmarshalling takes an XML representation of an object and converts it to a class. If you don't know what is there, then you need to post your code so we can see it.

Comment: Dakoda. I've posted the class which acts as entity/response.

Comment: And, the client code too.

Comment: You're substituting the real address, so to request.getServiceURL() in a browser and see what is there. I'll bet it's XML.

Comment: You are correct Dakota. This is what it says 

`This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`

Comment: There is no document tree at all.

Comment: Sorry, got sidetracked. open up the web page and paste it into a word document, although a standard text document reader will work. Match up the xml tags. That will tell you what the unmarshalling is complaining about.

Comment: Dakoda, the page is empty. There are no XML tags.

Comment: Inbound response is OK. 200 status code.

Comment: I did a web search for your mig.eis.client.EISClientException and didn't find any. What API are you using? or is it yours?

Comment: This is internal.

Comment: You're going to need a debugger for the code. Set breakpoint on response.readEntity(ThirdPartyValidateEMailAddressResponse.class); That's the only way.

Comment: This is what I have been doing and it fails while reading the entity. But I can't control that because this is client code, not sure if I need to configure anything in my side.

Comment: Can you get example code?

Comment: I've already posted it Dakoda. Please take a look at where it says Client Code.

Comment: Dakoda I got it... Thank you so much for your support.